# Why is only part of the object passing to the home controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net

From the menu page a user clicks an "Add to Order" button. The "Add to Order" button triggers the addToOrder function. That function works correctly, the drink is passed and an order is created with the drink information. After clicking the "Add to Order" button the user is sent to a confirmation page where their drink order is displayed and takes in their name in a form. The information passes correctly to the confirmation page, however when the form on the confirmation page is submitted the drink information is not passed but the rest of the form is. Any suggestions on how to get the drink information to pass in the object is greatly appreciated!

In the Home Controller:

From the menu page, this gets the drink information and works correctly:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult addToOrder(int id)
    {
     
        Drink drinkToAdd = _drinkRepository.GetDrink(id);
        List<Drink> dList = new List<Drink>();
        dList.Add(drinkToAdd);
        Order order = new Order();
        order.drinkList = dList;
        order.total = drinkToAdd.drinkPrice;
        ViewData.Model = order;
        return View("OrderConfirmation");
    }
```

This method gets the information from the form in the order confirmation page:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult confirmedOrder(Order order, int drinkID)
    {
        Drink drinkToAdd = _drinkRepository.GetDrink(drinkID);
        List<Drink> dList = new List<Drink>();
        dList.Add(drinkToAdd);
        order.drinkList = dList;
        _orderRepository.Add(order);
        return View("ThankYou");
    }
```

This is the order confirmation page:

```
 @model BartenderApp.Models.Order

@{ 
    ViewData["Title"] = "Order Confirmation";
}
   

<html>
<body>
    <h1>Order Confirmation</h1>
    <form asp-action="confirmedOrder" method="get" >
        <p>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName): @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)</p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LastName): @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)</p>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model.drinkList)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.drinkName)</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b> @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.drinkDescription)</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b> @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.drinkPrice)</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.drinkList)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.id, new { drinkID = item.id } )
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.drinkName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.drinkDescription)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.drinkPrice)
                    </td>>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p style="float:left">@Html.ActionLink("Modify Order", "Menu")</p>
        <p style="float:right"><b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.total):</b> $@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.total)</p>

        <input type="submit" value="Checkout" name="checkout" style="float:right" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

When I hit the submit button on the form I thought the entire object would pass but only the first and last name are. I have tried to then pass the specific drinkID so I could locate it in the repository and add it to the order. However, the drinkID is not passing either (always 0). Why is the drink information not passing with the rest of the object?

Thanks

This is the URL after I hit the submit button on the order confirmation page:
https://localhost:44378/Home/confirmedOrder?FirstName=John&LastName=Jones&item.id=1&item.id=1&checkout=Checkout

In this example, I did add the drink with the ID of 1 to my order. There is also another order in the repository, so the ID of the order is 2.

Comment: SInce it's a GET, you should be able to see the parameters in the address bar. Are they there?

Comment: Yes, they are. The first name, last name, and item.id are passed.

Comment: Does it show in the URL with `id` or `drinkID`?

Comment: It passes the drinkID

Comment: I understand you are trying to pass the drink ID. I am asking what shows up in the URL in the address bar to the left of the equals sign. Perhaps you could edit your question and paste the whole URL.

Comment: Please see the edits. Thank you!

Comment: Your markup needs to be changed in order to support a list of drinks. Please see here to get an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542389/asp-net-mvc-handling-multiple-objects-in-one-form